# Removing all references from a tuple using Oracle/Access

Tags: sql, oracle

I created a simple databse using Oracle that has several tables and a few constraints, i am using Access 2007 to interact with the database.

My problem is that I have a table that is called "Customer" which holds several fields, most notably a Primary Key called CUSTID.

I have another table called "Order" which uses the Primary Key in "Customer" as a Foreign Key.

Obviously if i try to delete a customer that is being used in "Order" i get an error as it's being used. This means i have to delete the particular order that references the Customer and then i can delete the Custome record.

I know that "cascade" should delete everything associated with it, my question is how can i do that from Access? I have limited knowledge of databases but enough to create one etc..

This is more of a validation thing, it's just a hassle to delete certain tuples before i can remove another.

This is the database created for Oracle:

```
--Used to create a "Clean" slate
DROP TABLE ITEM CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE CUSTOMER CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE CORDER CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE FORUM CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE TABLE ITEM 
(
ITEMID              NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
NAME               CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
CATEGORY            CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
PRICE    NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT ITEM_PK PRIMARY KEY (ITEMID)
);


INSERT INTO ITEM VALUES (1000,'CARROT SEEDS','PACKET SEEDS',2.99);
INSERT INTO ITEM VALUES (2250,'ROSES','FLOWERS',5.99);
INSERT INTO ITEM VALUES (3300,'TOMATOES','PACKET SEEDS',2.99);
INSERT INTO ITEM VALUES (4050,'POTATOES','PACKET SEEDS',1.99);


CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER 
(
 CUSTID              NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
 FNAME               CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 LNAME               CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 ADDRESS             CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
 CITY        CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
 PCODE               CHAR(7) NOT NULL,
 CNUMBER             NUMBER(11) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_PK PRIMARY KEY (CUSTID)
 );

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (1010,'JAMIE','KEELING','149 OLD MANSFIELD ROAD','DERBY','DE214SA',07500966490);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (2020,'HELEN','DARLINGTON','27 MOORPARK AVENUE','ROCHDALE','OL113JQ',07890189802);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (3030,'STEVEN','SEGAL','123 FAKE STREET','OHIO','SE095BG',01559345467);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (4040,'BRUCE','WAYNE','17 LAKEVIEW CRESCENT','CHICAGO','MN432BD',07500966490);


CREATE TABLE CORDER 
(
 ORDERID             NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
 CUSTID              NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
 SHIPADD    CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
 SHIPPCODE    CHAR(7) NOT NULL,
 SHIPDATE    DATE,
 ITEMID              NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
 QUANTITY    NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
 TOTAL     NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT ORDER_PK PRIMARY KEY (ORDERID),
 CONSTRAINT FK_CUSTOMER FOREIGN KEY (CUSTID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTID),
 CONSTRAINT FK_ITEM FOREIGN KEY (ITEMID) REFERENCES ITEM(ITEMID)
);

 INSERT INTO CORDER VALUES (1000,1010,'149 OLD MANSFIELD ROAD','DE214SA','12-JAN-07',1000,100,100.00);
 INSERT INTO CORDER VALUES (2000,2020,'27 MOORPARK AVENUE','OL113JQ','04-NOV-10',2250,200,100.00);
 INSERT INTO CORDER VALUES (3000,3030,'123 FAKE STREET','SE095BG','30-OCT-08',3300,150,100.00);
 INSERT INTO CORDER VALUES (4000,4040,'17 LAKEVIEW CRESCENT','MN432BD','25-JUL-07',4050,125,100.00);


 CREATE TABLE FORUM
 (
 FORUMID  NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
 TITLE   CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 THREADNAME  CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 POSTER   CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 POSTDATE  DATE,
 CONSTRAINT FORUM_PK PRIMARY KEY (FORUMID)
 );

 INSERT INTO FORUM VALUES (1001,'GENERAL CHAT','BEGINNER QUESTIONS','JAMIE KEELING', '25-NOV-09');
 INSERT INTO FORUM VALUES (2002,'OFF TOPIC','FAVOURITE BAND','HELEN DARLINGTON', '12-JAN-09');
 INSERT INTO FORUM VALUES (3003,'GENERAL CHAT','WHEN TO HARVEST?','BRUCE WAYNE', '02-NOV-08');
 INSERT INTO FORUM VALUES (4004,'OFF TOPIC','WHERE DO YOU LIVE?','STEVEN SEGAL', '13-JAN-08');
```

Comment: Why all those CHAR columns? Change them into varchar2 columns because varchar2 columns use less space, varchar2 columns don't have blank paddings.

Comment: This is simply to get it working, after it's fully functional i'll begin optimising

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard SQL way to create [foreign key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) with ON DELETE CASCADE is following. I don't know if Access supports this, but Oracle does have support for ON DELETE CASCADE.

```
alter table CORDER
add foreign key FK_CUSTOMER
references CUSTOMER(custid)
on delete cascade
```

If you are re-creating tables, you can also define the foreign keys with on delete cascade in table creation statement. i.e. replace this

```
CONSTRAINT FK_CUSTOMER FOREIGN KEY (CUSTID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTID)
```

with this

```
CONSTRAINT FK_CUSTOMER FOREIGN KEY (CUSTID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTID) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: It's not the question whether Access supports cascading deletes. The question is whether Oracle supports cascading deletes and Oracle does support cascading deletes.

Comment: Access is just the client, Oracle does the real job. However your SQL syntax will work.

Comment: Great, i'll have a fiddle using that when I'm back on the right computer, will update if it works =]